# Using Stream Reader and Stream Writer in TCP programming C# Causes missing data, usually after spaces

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, stream

I am making a simple server that can handle text commands in .NET 4.5 . Whenever there is a large segment that is transmitted, it usually is transmitted with a large portion missing from the frame. The missing target usually comes near spaces.

for example, if I transmit "Attempting connection to server at IP address: ", usually, all that will be transmitted is "Attempting connection". However, if I transmit "AttemptingconnectiontoserveratIPaddress:", then the entire frame is reliably transmitted.

Here is  the loop code for the client side, where Client is a form, and sr is a StreamReader and sw is a StreamWriter for the same socket. toSendToServer is a string that is passed between threads and acts as a buffer to send things.

```
        //main handling loop.
        Task<String> readVal = sr.ReadLineAsync();

        while(!Client.thisClient.IsDisposed && s.Connected){
            if (readVal.Status ==TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
                   String result = readVal.Result;
                   //printToConsole(result);
                   handleIncomingCommand(result.Split(' '));
                   readVal = sr.ReadLineAsync();
            }

            if (!toSendToServer.Equals("")) {
                sw.WriteLine(toSendToServer);
                sw.Flush();
                printToConsole(toSendToServer);
                toSendToServer = "";
            }
        }
```

the printToConsole method will always and entirely print whatever is supposed to be printed, so i know it's not an issue of thread safety.

Here is my server code:

```
        Task<String> readTask = reader.ReadLineAsync();
        //Main loop
        while (running && clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            if (readTask.Status ==TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                String result = readTask.Result;
                println(result);
                if(reader.Peek() != -1){
                    println("Buffer not cleared... Remaining buffer:");
                    println(reader.ReadLine());
                }
                if (result != null)
                {
                    String[] args = result.Split(' ');
                    Server.serverThread.sendCommand(username, args);
                }
                readTask = reader.ReadLineAsync();
            }
            if (toSend != null)
            {
                //.connect 131.212.37.205
                println("Sending \""+toSend+"\"");
                writer.Write(toSend);
                writer.Flush();
                toSend = null;
            }

        }
```

whenever the task returns with a result, it always gets clipped (Ie transmitting "Attempting connection to server at IP address: " causes the server to print  "Attempting connection", or sometimes even simply  "Attempting"). It is unreliable to determine what gets sent.

Why is it that some data gets lost in the stream, and further, why is it always centered around spaces?

I can only assume that since the reader only reads to the end of the line that the writer must somehow segment the data, preferring spaces, however, if this were the case, then the reader would still read the data on the next round of the loop, but in this case, only 1 line is ever read per line transmitted.

Comment: @MichaelRandall How come it's so hard if every man and his dog can do it?

Comment: Its hard to get them to work efficiently, and scalably, and reliably, dealing with all the fault modes of the tcp layer, abnormal disconnects, then as soon as you need to know more than just trivial hello world stuff, then you start to need to send message sizes or implement some sort of pseudo protocol on top of it.

Comment: I've just answered similar question. Take a look at this answer - message defragmentation part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626906/keeping-tcp-connection-alive/55629654#55629654

Comment: @BART I found the issue. It's due to the String toSend not being a thread safe data type.